# How to get the content from a meta tag via WKWebVie evaluateJavaScript?

Tags: javascript, swift, swiftui, wkwebview, meta-tags

I am trying to get the content of this tag:

```
<meta name="WT.z_docTitle" content="Judgment of the Court (Third Chamber) of 19 January 2023.#Administraci&oacute;n General del Estado and&nbsp;Others v Asociaci&oacute;n para la Defensa de los Intereses Comunes de las Autoescuelas (AUDICA) and Ministerio Fiscal.#Reference for a preliminary ruling &ndash; Directive 2006/123/EC &ndash; Services in the internal market &ndash; Article 2(2)(d) &ndash; Substantive scope &ndash; Service in the field of transport &ndash; Provision of road safety awareness and re-education courses for the recovery of driving licence points &ndash; Concession to operate a public service &ndash; Article 15 &ndash; Requirements &ndash; Division of the relevant territory into five lots &ndash; Quantitative and territorial limit on access to the activity concerned &ndash; Overriding reasons in the public interest &ndash; Justification &ndash; Road safety &ndash; Proportionality &ndash; Service of general economic interest.#Case C-292/21."/>
```

For the purpose I've built a WKWebView and try to evaluateJavaScript():

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct UIWebView: NSViewRepresentable {

typealias NSViewType = WKWebView

@Binding var toggle: Bool

let url: URL

func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
  
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    
    return webView
    
}

func updateNSView(_ nsView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    
    nsView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    if toggle {
        toggle.toggle()
        
        nsView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelector('meta[name=\"WT.z_docTitle\"]').content;") { (result, error) in
            
            if error == nil {
                print(result)
            } else {
                if let error = error as? WKError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

But then all I get is:

```
A JavaScript exception occurred
```

How to make the result be a string with the content, like this:

```
Judgment of the Court (Third Chamber) of 19 January 2023.#Administraci&oacute;n General del Estado and&nbsp;Others v Asociaci&oacute;n para la Defensa de los Intereses Comunes de las Autoescuelas (AUDICA) and Ministerio Fiscal.#Reference for a preliminary ruling &ndash; Directive 2006/123/EC &ndash; Services in the internal market &ndash; Article 2(2)(d) &ndash; Substantive scope &ndash; Service in the field of transport &ndash; Provision of road safety awareness and re-education courses for the recovery of driving licence points &ndash; Concession to operate a public service &ndash; Article 15 &ndash; Requirements &ndash; Division of the relevant territory into five lots &ndash; Quantitative and territorial limit on access to the activity concerned &ndash; Overriding reasons in the public interest &ndash; Justification &ndash; Road safety &ndash; Proportionality &ndash; Service of general economic interest.#Case C-292/21.
```